# Variables in dropdown MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I need a drop-down in my view which contains the years from 2012 to present (I could be seeing this code 5 years later)
How can i put a variable in drop-down?
I can put them manually but then I would have to change the code each year.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
public function generateYearDropDown($from, $to){
   $dropdown_text = '<select id="year" name="year">';

    for($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++)
        $dropdown_text .= '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</>'; 

   $dropdown_text .= '</select>';
   return $dropdown_text;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo generateYearDropDown(2012,(int) date('Y'));
```

That will create a html code like:

```
<select id="year" name="year">
    .............
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    .............
</select>
```